# In new iOS9 multi tasking system, how do we get width/height of application

Tags: ios

Before iOS9 multi-tasking operation come out, we get the application size by calling the following method (written in objective-c)

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
```

But this method is calling UIScreen, so I am not sure whether it is still applicable to iOS9. Because you now want to get the application size rather than the screen size.

Comment: Your code is broken on iOS 7 or on iOS 8, depending on how you use it. One iOS version gives the screen size, independent on UI rotation, the other gives it dependent on rotation. What about trying it out?

Comment: Check `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] bounds]` ?

Comment: @gnasher729 thanks I know in iOS7 the screen size is always portrait mode while in iOS8 the screen size will change. It is just an example.

Comment: @chedabob thanks for the comment. Yeah you may be right about it.

Answer (score 0):

It was a while ago I did this, but `self.view.size` or something like that.

Comment: @EthanFang Then you will get the size of the view instead of the screen.